# JSDoc and documenting returned object literal with functions

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, object-literal

I currently use JSDoc to document my AMD modules and class definitions. For example:

```
define([], function() {

    /**
     * @class Mocks HTTP requests
     * @name test/xhr/RequestMocks
     * @param {String} method
     */
    function RequestMocks(method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a mock
     * @param {String} url
     * @returns {RequestMockConfig}
     * @memberOf test/xhr/RequestMocks
     */
    RequestMocks.prototype.addMock = function(url) {    
        var mock = {
            url: url,
            status: 200
        };

        // TODO register this mock somewhere

        /*
         * WHAT TO TYPE HERE? 
         * I would like to name this object "RequestMockConfig"
         * and have it appear on test/xhr/RequestMocks JSDoc page
         */
        return {
            /**
             * Mocks the http response status
             * @param {Number} status
             * @returns {RequestMockConfig}
             */
            status: function(status) {
                mock.status = status;
                return this;
            },
            /**
             * Mocks the http response body
             * @param {Object} response
             * @returns {RequestMockConfig}
             */
            response: function(response) {
                mock.response = JSON.stringify(response);
                return this;
            }
        };
    };

    return RequestMocks;

});
```

I'd use it like this:

```
var mockedGetRequests = new RequestMocks('GET');
mockedGetRequests.addMock('/my/url')
    .status(404)
    .response({ error: 'Not found' });
mockedGetRequests.addMock('/my/url2')
    .response({ data: 'my data' });
```

What is the correct way of documenting the returned object literal `RequestMockConfig` and it's functions, `status()` and `response()`?

I aware of the `@typedef` tag, but it seems like it's only useful for defining simple objects which contain no functions.

Comment: I guess by making a new Object with RequestMockConfig and then returning `new RequestMockConfig(obj)`

Comment: You mean define the `RequestMockConfig` constructor elsewhere and add the methods to it's prototype and then use it in `addMock()`? I was also aware of this, but I think it would just make the code more complicated, instead of more readable.

Comment: Yes, and then you should ask yourself what you find more important, structure + docs or simplicity? imo it wouldn't make it more complicated. more structured instead

Comment: OK, say I do define a new class just for this. Is there a way I can make it display on the same page as the documentation of the `RequestMocks` class, and not on a separate page? I wouldn't want to clutter the documentation list with private classes, as the user will never be able to instatiate them manually.

Comment: I have no too much xp with JSDoc, but what about defining `RequestMocks.Config` in the same module?

Comment: That would make the constructor pubilc. I ended up marking the `RequestMockConfig` as `@protected`, even though it would be more correct to mark it as `@private`, but then jsdoc doesn't generate the documentation for that class if i don't use the `--private` flag. Thanks for the help.

Comment: no problem, don't forget to answer your own question in 2 days :)